# Getting exception when trying to open a new page with Navigator

Tags: flutter

I have a push notification manager class that is singleton where I listen for notifications from `Firebase FCM` and I handle them based on the logic and open specific screens.

I init with `BuildContext` that `PushtNotificatonManager` class inside `HomePage` that iS called from `main.dart`.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    PushNotificationsManager().listen(context);
  }
```

This is code from `main.dart`

```
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
  print('Content of message: ' + message.toString());
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  configureInjections();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  runApp(SayApp());
}
```

This is part of the code from `PushNotificationsManager` class

```
@injectable
class PushNotificationsManager {
  static final PushNotificationsManager _instance = PushNotificationsManager._internal();

  factory PushNotificationsManager() {
    return _instance;
  }

  PushNotificationsManager._internal();

  Future<void> listen(BuildContext context) async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      NotificationSettings settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true,
      );
      if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
        print('User granted permission');
        await _handleNotifications(context);
      }
    } else {
      await _handleNotifications(context);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleNotifications(BuildContext context) async {
    // gives the message on which user taps and it opened the app from terminated state
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      if (message != null) {
        openNotification(message, context);
      }
    });

    // foreground
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      if (message.notification != null) {
        _showInAppNotification(message);
      }
    });

    // When the app is in background but opened and user taps on the notification
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      openNotification(message, context);
    });
  }
```

Inside `showInAppNotifications` I am trying to display notifications as pop up and when the user clicks on it, I try to open a specific screen.

```
  void _displayInAppNotifications(RemoteMessage message) {
    FlutterRingtonePlayer.playNotification();
    showOverlayNotification((context) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          openNotification(message, context);
          OverlaySupportEntry.of(context)!.dismiss();
        },
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: message.data[NotificationType.NOTIFICATION_TYPE] ==
                      NotificationType.PRIVATE_MESSAGE_1_ON_1
                  ? Avatar(text: message.notification!.title!)
                  : SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: const Size(40, 40),
                      child: ClipOval(
                          child: Container(
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(SvgIcons.sayAppWaveLogo),
                      ))),
              title:
                  Text(message.notification!.title!, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, maxLines: 1),
              subtitle: Text(
                message.notification!.body!,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 2,
              ),
              trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                  onPressed: () {
                    OverlaySupportEntry.of(context)!.dismiss();
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }, duration: Duration(seconds: 4), position: NotificationPosition.top);
  }
```

I have this method `navigateToChannelDetailsPage` that is called from the above method and here I am getting an exception.

```
  Future<void> navigateToChannelDetailsPage(ChannelEntity channel, BuildContext context) async {
    var cubit = BlocProvider.of<HomeCubit>(context);
    var isUserChannelMember = await cubit.isCurrentUserChannelMember(channel);

    if (!isUserChannelMember) return;

    var isUserMutedPublic = await cubit.getIsUserMutedPublic(channel);

    if (isUserMutedPublic) channel.isUserMutedPublic = isUserMutedPublic;

    return PageNavigator.navigate(
            context, ChannelDetailsPage(channel: channel, isFromAdminNotification: true))
        .then((_) {
      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
      cubit.updateChannelMemberChatDetailsDataOnChannelClosed(channel);
    });
  }
```

This is the exception:

```
E/flutter (25412): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (25412): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter (25412): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
E/flutter (25412): #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4241:9)
E/flutter (25412): #1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4255:6)
E/flutter (25412): #2      Element.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4286:12)
E/flutter (25412): #3      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:339:38)
E/flutter (25412): #4      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:293:30)
E/flutter (25412): #5      BlocProvider.of (package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_provider.dart:100:23)
E/flutter (25412): #6      PushNotificationsManager.navigateToChannelDetailsPage (package:say_app/presentation/notification/push_notifications_manager.dart:204:30)
E/flutter (25412): #7      PushNotificationsManager.openNotification (package:say_app/presentation/notification/push_notifications_manager.dart:180:9)
E/flutter (25412): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because, by the time you wait for some things to finish the execution, you do something else on the app (go back one or few screens let's say) so your widget/screen gets disposed of and is no longer in the widget tree when you call `PageNavigator.navigate(context, ...)`.
So to prevent that from happening, you can use the `mounted` flag to check if your `StatefulWidget` is still active, like:

```
if(mounted) PageNavigator.navigate(context, ...)
```

But in that case, the page will not get pushed if the widget is disposed of. So if you still want to push the new screen, no matter what happens in the meantime (even if that widget gets disposed of), you can have your global `navigatorKey` which you assign to the `MaterialApp` `key` property and use the context from `navigatorKey` while navigating, since it should always be usable (i.e. the `MaterialApp` should always be present in the widget tree). Solution example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

So now you navigate like:

```
PageNavigator.navigate(navigatorKey.currentContext!, ...) // your use case
Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!).push(...) // the usual way using global navigatorKey
```

Comment: How I can access GlobalKey in my PushNotificationsManager, which is just a singleton and it is not widget?

Comment: You just need to import `main.dart` since the global variable `navigatorKey` is defined there.

Comment: That did not help, since now I am getting this error: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, in the `main.dart` file, instead of `MaterialApp(key: navigatorKey)` it should be `MaterialApp(navigatorKey: navigatorKey)`. I'll correct my answer right away.